# Multiple insert in single transaction using multithreading

Tags: multithreading, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am using springboot Jpa and marked a method as transactional.
In the transactional method, multiple inserts are there which are independent of each other.

I am trying to improve the performance by using multiple threads inside the transactional method but Transactional behavior is lost when I did this.
Can you please suggest a way to achieve this behavior.

```
@Transactional
methodA(){

    repo1.save(A)
    repo2.save(B)
    repo3.save(C)
    repo4.save(D)

}
```

I want to run these save operations in different threads but in one single transaction.

Comment: Use TransactionTemplate for programmatic tx management. But multithreading most likely won't improve performance in this scenario.

Comment: Can you suggest something that can help in improving performance

Comment: This is mostly about architecture, and for that I'd need to ask more specific questions. And you'd first need to research what exactly slows it down.

Comment: Time is taken during the insert calls, only this part of the application runs in a single thread. Here, above as I mentioned 4 repositories but in actual there are 15 insert statements, so they do insert one by one and slows down the application.

Comment: What do you mean it runs in single thread? This is called by your Controller->Service? Then it's called by user-threads. And 15 insert statements should finish fast, probably less than half a sec..

Comment: What I mean is, the business logic processing to create data takes place in separate user threads. After all the business logic processing completed on 15 objects, all the 15 instances passed to dao. From that DAO this save method is called in a single transaction .
So, I was looking if this 15 insert statements can go parallely